# How to read in specific numbers from a txt file C++

Tags: c++, file, nested-loops

The problem I am having is that I do not know how to read a specific number out of a text file that was created and had values entered into it earlier in the program.

I was hoping to use a nested loop statement for reading in the values after the values of the quizes are read in I need to add up the values and average them out and this needs to happen multiple times

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string StudentGrades;
    int studentID;
    double quiz1;
    double quiz2;
    double quiz3;
    double quiz4;
    double total=0;
    double choice;
    ofstream outFile;   

    cout << "Enter student ID number, Quiz 1 Grade, Quiz 2 Grade , Quiz 3 Grade, Quiz 4 Grade" << endl;
    outFile.open("StudentGrades.txt");
    //while (outFile.open)
    //{
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            cout << "Enter student ID: ";
            cin >> studentID;
            cout << "Enter quiz grade 1: ";
            cin >> quiz1;
            //cout << quiz1;
            cout << "Enter quiz grade 2: ";
            cin >> quiz2;
            //cout << quiz2;
            cout << "Enter quiz grade 3: ";
            cin >> quiz3;
            //cout << quiz3;
            cout << "Enter quiz grade 4: ";
            cin >> quiz4;
            //cout << quiz4;
            cout << endl;
            //outFile.open("StudentGrades.txt");
            if (outFile.is_open())
            {
                cout << "inside if/else outFile" << endl;
                //outFile << "File successfully open";

                outFile << studentID << " " << quiz1 << " " << quiz2 << " " << quiz3 << " " << quiz4 << endl;

            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Error opening file";
            }

            cout << "Enter 0 for no more students. Enter 1 for more students." << endl;
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 1)
                continue;
            if (choice == 0)
            {
                outFile.close();
                break;
            }

        }

    //}
    //declaring file and opening it






        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open("StudentGrades.txt");

        while (inFile>>studentID)
        {
            cout << studentID<< quiz1 <<quiz2<<quiz3<<quiz4<< endl;
        }



    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You should post both the text file and the code

Comment: Write code that does what you require.

Comment: The text file is created while the code is running

Comment: I will be honest I barely know what I am doing here using text files in coding is one of the most difficult things I've learned so far which isnt much

Comment: Make sure to state *exactly* what your trying to achieve, so people can solve in the optimal way

Answer (score 1):

You are not reading all the fields from the input file, you are reading just the `studentID`.

```
while (inFile>>studentID)
{
    cout << studentID<< quiz1 <<quiz2<<quiz3<<quiz4<< endl;
}
```

Try:

```
while (inFile >> studentID >> quiz1 >> quiz2 >> quiz3 >> quiz4)
{
    cout << studentID << quiz1 << quiz2 << quiz3 << quiz4 << endl;
}
```

**Update**

Below is my suggestion for a refactored program. It's good to create functions that perform specific tasks and then call them from a higher level function instead of jamming them all in one large function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void saveStudentData(string const& filename)
{
   int studentID;
   double quiz1;
   double quiz2;
   double quiz3;
   double quiz4;

   // Use int type for choice, not double
   int choice;

   ofstream outFile(filename);
   if (!outFile.is_open())
   {
      // Problem opening file.
      cout << "Error opening file";
      return;
   }

   cout << "Enter student ID number, Quiz 1 Grade, Quiz 2 Grade , Quiz 3 Grade, Quiz 4 Grade" << endl;
   for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
   {
      cout << "Enter student ID: ";
      cin >> studentID;
      cout << "Enter quiz grade 1: ";
      cin >> quiz1;
      cout << "Enter quiz grade 2: ";
      cin >> quiz2;
      cout << "Enter quiz grade 3: ";
      cin >> quiz3;
      cout << "Enter quiz grade 4: ";
      cin >> quiz4;
      cout << endl;

      outFile << studentID << " " << quiz1 << " " << quiz2 << " " << quiz3 << " " << quiz4 << endl;

      cout << "Enter 0 for no more students. Enter 1 for more students." << endl;
      cin >> choice;
      if (choice == 0)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}

void readStudentData(string const& filename)
{
   int studentID;
   double quiz1;
   double quiz2;
   double quiz3;
   double quiz4;
   double total=0;

   ifstream inFile(filename);
   while (inFile >> studentID >> quiz1 >> quiz2 >> quiz3 >> quiz4)
   {
      total = (quiz1 + quiz2 + quiz3 + quiz4); 
      cout << studentID << " " << quiz1 << " " << quiz2
           << " " << quiz3 << " " << quiz4 << " " << total << endl;
   }
}

int main()
{
   string filename("StudentGrades.txt");
   saveStudentData(filename);
   readStudentData(filename);
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: When I do this I should be able to add up the quiz 1 2 3 and 4 right? or am I going about this all wrong

Comment: @ConnorLance, yes you should be able to.

Comment: It only prints out the last numbers entered not all of them

Comment: @ConnorLance, not sure what's going on in your run environment. It works for me.

Comment: Poor choice of words what I meant was that it is only adding up and averaging the the first set of quizes entered not all of the sets